# Can you invent html attributes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a website using HTML5. I have a jQuery script that shows a custom tooltip  on all elements that have the `title` attribute. I also have a script that makes an alert message appear when the user clicks a picture. The alert message will say what the `title` attribute equals. Unfortunately the tooltip script and the alert script interfere with each other.

**My question is:**

1. Can I make up an attribute?

Comment: data-* is the way to go

Comment: Could you share some code that goes along with the question? It's not clear how they conflict.

Comment: Inventing your own attributes is possible, but it's a very bad practice IMHO.

Comment: Yes you can. You can create just about any attribute you'd like, but it won't be valid HTML, for that you would need data attributes, where you again can create any attribute you'd like as long as it starts with `data-*` and it will be valid in HTML5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not exactly, but HTML 5 provides [`data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-%2a-attributes).

Comment: yes it does , you can ! , you need to prefix them

Answer (score 2):

In html5 , use data-XX to produce extra attributes.

see : http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Comment: that was a little slow :) )

Comment: Thanks, that answers it! I would vote you up, but that requires 15 reputation. :(

Comment: don't mind the vote :) , we all gave you the same answer

Answer (score 1):

You can make an aditional attribute, just by naming it.

```
<img src="abc.jpg" data-opens="abc" data-test="abc" id="image" />
```

And access it in jQuery by typing

```
$("#image").attr("data-opens")..
```

Like:

```
alert($("#image").attr("data-opens") + " " + $("#image").attr("data-test"));
```

Edited, thanks to GCyrillus.

Comment: The good way is to add the prefix data- So you can clearly access to attributes you made up.

Comment: Thanks! Also helpful. I would vote you up too, but that requires 15 reputation... again.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically answering you question: you can make up attributes.

But your HTML will no longer be valid and since you are adding them just to store information, you should use de `data-*` form to add you own data storage for an element, plus it will still be a valid HTML